# Unable to select options of a select box in internet explorer

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer

I'm trying to do a custom tooltip for my webpage and everything seems to be fine except for select box and Internet Explorer (IE). After adding my tooltip, IE does not allow me to select any option. I can click the select box to show options, but then as soon as i mouse over the options, the select box closes itself.

You can observe it clearly using this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6MzD3/). Try opening it in Firefox and Internet Explorer. In Firefox it works fine, but in IE, the select box closes itself as soon as you try to select one of the options.

How can I make it work properly in IE?

Comment: What is your problem? Please state your question. We are not here to research your problem. State it. I couldn't identify if there are any difference.

Comment: You mean that the tool tip is coming front to your select box, which is not letting you to select the options?

Comment: @Dibya: problem is select box is closing itself when i tried to mouse over on my options.

Comment: @venkateshwar: that is not my problem  my problem is select box is closing itself when i tried to mouse over on the options of select box i.e., it is not allowing me to select any option in internet explorer

Comment: @Dibya: still not clear let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you really need `title` for this controls? You can use `data attributes` and everything will be fine. For example: http://jsfiddle.net/6MzD3/16/. Also look at [Plugins/Authoring](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring) and create simple plugin for tooltip without hardcoded selectors.

Comment: well not the exact answer i wanted but it solved my purpose. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Try close some line code, change it like this below:

```
 ...

   this.t = this.title;
   // this.title = "";
   $("body").append("<p id='tooltip'>"+ this.t +"</p>");
 ... 
   //this.title = this.t;
   $("#tooltip").remove();
 ...
```

Comment: @PraveenKumar,@Fredy then you will see two tooltips simultaneously one from the default and other is the one you just added. the point of removing the default title  should not be shown when mouse over occurs

Answer (score 2):

You need to explicitly tell IE to stop propagation within your function as it is applying the hover to the child option elements as well.

```
$('*.tooltip').hover(function(e)
{
    e.stopPropagation();

    ...
}
```

[Original Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6MzD3/1/)

This works in IE7, 8 and 9:

Added a conditional clause to check for a select box in the event object.

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6MzD3/11/)

Comment: Still the same issue with IE 9!

Comment: Additional / different fix for you in answer

Comment: Er... Is it just me? Still the same issue... Checking in IE 8: Nopes! When the `.remove()` event occurs, this problem comes! :(

Comment: still not allowing to select the options checked in IE8.

Comment: Yeah was a problem with it, not a good solution... updated fiddle works in IE7, 8 and 9.

Comment: Additional: Still not perfect, the problem with IE is the changing of the title attribute shuts the select box. Quick google search came up with no viable solutions other than handling select boxes differently in regards to your tooltips.

Comment: @DavidBarker: it is not removing the tooltip even after mouseOut and should consider reassigning title back before return but tooltip is not removed.

Comment: Yeah thats the problem in IE, reassign the title and select box dissapears. Unless anyones got a clever solution to that, only way I can see is to write a conditional and hold the value of the select until the hover function has finished and then re-assign it.